# Tape Measure app for Android

Tags: android

Can anyone recommend a **tape measure app for Android**?

I want to be able to use an Android device as a simple tape measure to measure things from 10" (25cm) to 16' (5m).

Although a would prefer a single app, it's okay if it needs to be two apps: one for short lengths (10"-24"), and another for longer lengths (24"-16').  I already have a good app to measure lengths under 5", and I can accurately estimate lengths from 5" to 10".

I have tried countless apps, and none of them seem to work well.  Many require carrying around another "reference" object" and taking a photo exactly parallel with the object.  I would prefer something that does not require a reference object or having to be exactly parallel to the object.

Ideally, I would like something as simple and fast as using a tape measure, perhaps even faster.

Accuracy is important.  Accurate to within 2% (or better) would be ideal.  That means it's okay if it is off by a quarter of an inch for a foot, or 4 inches for 16'.  That's obviously worse than a tape measure, but I'm willing to trade 2% of accuracy for the convenience.  At the least, I would like it to be accurate to the nearest inch for short measurements, and to the nearest foot for long ones.  More accuracy, of course, is better.

Must be compatible with Android KitKat.

I would prefer a gratis (free of cost) app, but paid apps are acceptable.  Open-source would be nice, but is definitely not required.

Comment: You need specific hardware for this.  I can not see how an app can do this with standard android hardware.  Laser Measurers from your local tool shop is the answer.

Comment: @RohitGupta If you can't see how it can be done, you will need to expand your imagination! :-)  I have found many clever apps that perform measurements without lasers, but I have yet to find a good one that meets the requirements I specified.

Comment: *If you have high accuracy, field-usage requirements calling for sub-meter results you should not be using a typical retail Android device.* From: http://www.andygup.net/how-accurate-is-android-gps-part-2-consuming-real-time-locations/

Comment: @JanDoggen That's a great article.  But this question has nothing do to with GPS.  (Obviously, GPS can't be used to measure the difference between 11" and 12" or even 30" and 32"... not even with the most accurate and sophisticated GPS devices in the world, to my understanding.)

Comment: But how is such an app supposed to work then, especially without a reference object? You may want to put that in your question.